# Can't mock Path extension function

Tags: mockk

This test fails. I got the package-class string from the decompiled class.

```kotlin
@Test
fun `path does not exist`() {
        mockkStatic("kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt")
        val nonExistentPath: Path = mockk(relaxed = true)
        every { nonExistentPath.exists() } returns false
        assertThat(nonExistentPath.exists()).isFalse
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround don't call the extension function, but a JVM function via `File`:

```kotlin
every { nonExistentPath.toFile().exists() } returns false
```

and use

```kotlin
Path.toFile().exists()
```

in the production code.